# SWTChart not redraw when it is inside a loop

Tags: java, swt, swtchart

If I have the following loop:

```
Chart plot = new Chart(composite, SWT.NONE);
ISeriesSet seriesSet = plot.getSeriesSet();
ISeries series = seriesSet.createSeries(SeriesType.LINE, "Test");

for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    points = ...
    series.setYSeries(points);
}
```

The chart is not refreshed quickly enough, even if I add a delay within the loop. I had to minimize the window and then maximize it to see the changes, in other words, it is not refreshed after every loop, I tried to force a refresh by adding this lines inside the loop:

```
plot.redraw();
plot.layout(true, true);
```

But seems like it is refreshed only once at the end of the loop. Is there a best practice I should be following when having to quickly refreshing the chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is running in the UI thread and will block UI updates until you return to the main `Display.readAndDispatch` loop. Code in the main UI thread must execute quickly and return to the main loop as soon as possible. The UI is only updated when `readAndDispatch` is executed.

So you can't use a simple `for` loop in the UI thread to update the chart.

One way to do this is to use `Display.timerExec` to run a single step after a delay.

Or you can start a background thread and put your loop there. From a background thread you must call `Display.syncExec` to run the code which updates the UI.